# Android Firebase Realtime database not showing written data in console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Realtime Database and Firebase Authentication.

In my app, I can successfully write into my database but some reason the data that is written does not show up on the console. I am unsure how to fix this. Any help is appreciated.

My database rules are set to true for read and write and I followed set up instructions.

- I tried removing firebase from my Android app and reinstalling it.
- Removing Firebase project and making a new firebase project

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data) and the code that doesn't work the way you expect. Please respond using @AlexMamo